# How do decode URL entities in java?

Tags: java, utf-8, decode

I'm trying to decode html entities in Java, but I noticed that

```
URLDecoder.decode(String stringToDecode, String charset);
```

is deprecated.

What should I use instead of it?

Comment: You are talking about URL Encoding entities (the ones starting with %), while the title speaks about HTML entities (the ones starting with &). These are two very different things, and the question title is misleading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method you mention is not deprecated. See here -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

```
URLDecoder.decode(String stringToDecode)
```

on the other hand is.

Answer (score 1):

It is not deprecated. The decode method with two parameters is not deprecated. Please check again. The first parameter is the String to decode; the second is the name of the character encoding to use (e.g., "UTF-8").

Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Answer (score 0):

It's [not deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). The overloaded decode method that doesn't take a character encoding argument is deprecated.