# Encode URL in JavaScript to prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, xss, encode

In my web application, URL is composed in JavaScript. This is URL to a Servlet.
This URL contains < > operators which cause third party application (SiteMinder) to display XSS warning & the URL is not loaded.

I am new to Java & web programming. After searching on net, I came to know that HTML entities should be used to resolve this.

Not sure how to do this, I used JavaScript string replace() function to replace as shown in code below,

```
txtvar = encodeURIComponent(document.form1.txt1.value);
txtvar = txtvar.replace(/%3C/g,"&lt;");
txtvar = txtvar.replace(/%3E/g,"&gt;");
txtvar = txtvar.replace(/'/g,"&apos;");
txtvar = txtvar.replace(/%22/g,"&quot;");
```

It worked fine in Internet Explorer but failed in Chrome & Firefox. Not sure but I suspect & (< and >) in the URL causes Chrome & Firefox to think that what follows is a new key value pair & it is ripped off.

Is there any setting in Chrome & Firefox to make it work like IE? I don't understand why it doesn't work in Firefox & Chrome and works fine in IE.

I then tried escaping & in < and > with %26,

```
txtvar=txtvar.replace(/&/g,"%26");
```

It allowed URL to load but in the servlet what I get is `&lt;` or `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.  It doesn't interpret them correctly.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Awadhoot

Comment: All you need to do is decode it on the server-side. As you are passing encoded values to server, server considers it as a string, not HTML, so you'll need to decode the text on server-side,

Comment: Can you explain more? I am new to Java & web programming. How should encode & decode?

Comment: Go through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306607/how-do-decode-html-entities-in-java

Comment: Do you think what I have done so far is correct, the way i have encoded?

Comment: If the code fulfills your requirement, I guess its correct. Though I would recommend to use standard library to encode html text string. Go through:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I have used encodeURIComponent() to escape the URL. But I believe it will not convert HTML characters (%3C, %3E) to HTML entities ( &lt;, &gt;)       Is there any library in Javascript to convert HTML characters to HTML entities?

Comment: I have used encodeURIComponent() to escape the URL. But I believe it will not convert HTML characters (%3C, %3E) to HTML entities ( &lt;, &gt;)       Is there any library in Javascript to convert HTML characters to HTML entities? Chrome didn't allow &lt; to be sent in URL. It considers & as a separator & following characters (lt;) are ripped off. So replaced &lt; with %26lt;. This URL is loaded but Servlet doesn't understand that &lt; is acutally <. I tried java.net.URLDecoder.decode(). But it doesn 't convert HTML entities back to HTML characters. Is there anything in Java to do this?

Comment: Try using StringEscapeUtils in servlet:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html